# Google Play Beta - No notifications, Current Version Varies with device

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I've published an app on Google Play.  I uploaded the APK to Beta Testing.  I have no APK in Production.  I added a Google Group for testing, and I accepted the invitation to test the app with my beta tester gmail user account.  I was able to install the Beta APK onto my device.

Just as a test, I incremented the versionName and versionCode in the AndroidManifest.  The package name is the same.  Nothing else in the Manifest changed. I exported and signed the APK with the same key.  I uploaded this new APK to Beta Testing.

Now I have two version in Beta Testing.  Version 1 and Version 2.  Version 1 Status is Unpublished.  Version 2 Status is Pubished.  I published Version 2 to Beta testing 24 hours ago.  I still received no notification on my device.  I received no email in my beta tester gmail account.  When I browse to the app in a browser on the device, the app Current Version states Varies with Device.  The Size says Varies with Device.  And the Requires Android version is incorrect.

How can I get Google Play to notify my beta tester when a new beta release is published to Google Play Beta?

Comment: same here.  
---- (new line, all this markdown stuff doesn't seem to work...)
as an attempt to work around this issue, I tried to uninstall the older beta version, hoping to find the newer beta version, but Play Store app reports an error.

issue reported via https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en, fingers crossed...